# I want to get difference between two timestamps which are filled in a php form

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, datediff, php-5.2

I have a HTML form which takes the data from the user as open_date and close_date. When the form is submitted, the data will be loaded into a MYSQL database.

What i want is:
I have a column in my database which stores difference between these two timestamps in hours.

Could you please help me in getting the solution?

Comment: What date format? please show sample data.

Comment: excuse me, I didn't see any code. Do you mind to share?

Comment: It is a UNIX date format (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS)

Answer (score 2):

### function

```
 function dateDiff($time1, $time2, $precision = 6) {
    // If not numeric then convert texts to unix timestamps
    if (!is_int($time1)) {
      $time1 = strtotime($time1);
    }
    if (!is_int($time2)) {
      $time2 = strtotime($time2);
    }

    // If time1 is bigger than time2
    // Then swap time1 and time2
    if ($time1 > $time2) {
      $ttime = $time1;
      $time1 = $time2;
      $time2 = $ttime;
    }

    // Set up intervals and diffs arrays
    $intervals = array('year','month','day','hour','minute','second');
    $diffs = array();

    // Loop thru all intervals
    foreach ($intervals as $interval) {
      // Create temp time from time1 and interval
      $ttime = strtotime('+1 ' . $interval, $time1);
      // Set initial values
      $add = 1;
      $looped = 0;
      // Loop until temp time is smaller than time2
      while ($time2 >= $ttime) {
        // Create new temp time from time1 and interval
        $add++;
        $ttime = strtotime("+" . $add . " " . $interval, $time1);
        $looped++;
      }

      $time1 = strtotime("+" . $looped . " " . $interval, $time1);
      $diffs[$interval] = $looped;
    }

    $count = 0;
    $times = array();
    // Loop thru all diffs
    foreach ($diffs as $interval => $value) {
      // Break if we have needed precission
      if ($count >= $precision) {
    break;
      }
      // Add value and interval 
      // if value is bigger than 0
      if ($value > 0) {
    // Add s if value is not 1
    if ($value != 1) {
      $interval .= "s";
    }
    // Add value and interval to times array
    $times[] = $value . " " . $interval;
    $count++;
      }
    }

    // Return string with times
    return implode(", ", $times);
  }
```

### Usage

```
echo dateDiff("2010-01-26", "2004-01-26") . "\n";
echo dateDiff("2006-04-12 12:30:00", "1987-04-12 12:30:01") . "\n";
echo dateDiff("now", "now +2 months") . "\n";
echo dateDiff("now", "now -6 year -2 months -10 days") . "\n";
echo dateDiff("2009-01-26", "2004-01-26 15:38:11") . "\n";
```

the link tell you all about date difference

http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/php-calculate-real-differences-between-two-dates-or-timestamps/

Comment: Thanks a lot..i tried it with few modifications and i got what i want..Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can:

```
$timeDiff = strtotime('2012-07-08 13:43:22') - strtotime('2012-07-07 12:13:12');

echo round($timeDiff / 60 / 60);
```